# i to the power of i and other complex exponentials

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, exponentiation

After stumbling accross $i^i$, I have been become quite obsessed with complex numbers and especially complex exponentials.

This even increased after realising that $i^i = e^{-\pi(2k + \frac{1}{2})} $ with $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ - which means that $i^i$ has infinite solutions.

I do understand how to get to these  formulas, so I'm **not** searching for a proof for $i^i$ being the above stated.

Yet, I didn't find any hint for a visual "proof", meaningfull representation of these formulas, real world use or an application in another field of mathematics, which I would like to know about.

Do you know about any of those/ have any hints towards them?

---

This is what I found/ know about so far (mainly videos explaining $i^i$ and $\sqrt[i]{i}$ and general complex stuff ):

- $i^i$ and co: The youtube channel of blackpenredpen
- Moivre, multiplikation and roots of complex numbers (from university)
- I do know 3blue1brown, but I did not watch all of his videos about complex numbers yet (so a hint that a certain video maybe helpfull for me, may help me)

Comment: Two minor things:
- English is my second language, please tell me if I am using terms wrongly
-if this is the wrong site for that, please tell me what the right site is for these kind of questions

Comment: Step 1 $i^i=e^{iln(i)}$.  $ln(i)$ is multi-valued.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, yes I know, because: ln(i) = pi*i*(2*x + 1/2) - what I'm searching for is a "deeper reason" beyond eulers identity for ln(i) being multivalued, thanks nonetheless ^^

Comment: I have no idea what a "deeper reason" would be.

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes,  I admit, that this might be not the right word;

Let me explain it like this: I can shove the formals around, getting the result like you showed, but there are certain ways (for a reference, see 3blue1browns videos) that show kinda a new aspect to something - I will try to rewrite the question in a better way

Comment: There really isn't anything deep.  Once we define that $e^{\theta i};\theta \in \mathbb R$ is defined as $\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ everything that follows is inevitable.

Comment: I am not sure how to approach it, but you might look at the expression for $ln(i)$ for "deeper meaning".

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: $i^i=e^{iln(i)}$.  $ln(i)$ is multi-valued.  Next $i=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}$, so $ln(i)=i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)$   Therefore $i^i=e^{-(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}$

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing deep.

We define that for any real $\theta$ that $e^{\theta i } = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.

And after that we have no choice.

......

For any non-zero complex number $z = Re(z) + iIm(z)$ we can define $r_z = |z| = \sqrt{Re^2(z)+Im^2(z)}$ and $\theta_z = \arctan \frac {Im(z)}{Re(z)}$ so that $z = r_z e^{\theta_z i}$.

And from that point on our hands are tied.

.......

For any non-zero complex numbers, $w$ and $z$ then the value $w^z$ *MUST* be equal to:

$(r_w e^{\theta_w i})^z =$

$r_w^z\cdot e^{z\theta_w i} = $

$e^{z\ln r_w + z\theta_w i} = $

$e^{[Re(z)\ln r_w - Im(z)\theta_w] + [Im(z)\ln r_w + Re(z)\theta_w]i}=$

$[e^{[Re(z)\ln r_w - Im(z)\theta_w]}][ e^{i [Im(z)\ln r_w + Re(z)\theta_w]}] = $

$R*(\cos W + i \sin W)$ where

$R$ is the positive real number $e^{[Re(z)\ln r_w - Im(z)\theta_w]}$ and $W$ is the real number $Im(z)\ln r_w + Re(z)\theta_w$.

That *has* to be how complex numbers to complex number powers *must* fall out.

We had no choice.

Comment: ok, i guess the word "deep" leads to the wrong direction -

Yet this answer actually helped me somewhat, yet wasn't what I actually searched for - but that's probably my own fault with the in concrete question

(I'd like to upvote your answer for the effort, but unforntunatly I do not have enough reputation - and like I said isn't the answer I searched)